# How to check if user has bookmarked item

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

hopefully I can nail down the point of this question in a precise manner the first time around, so here goes nothing:

I am attempting to create an application that provides users the ability to bookmark items of their choosing.  However, working with the Firebase data structure, I do not know how to check whether a user has already bookmarked the item(s) being displayed.

The relevant part of the HTML is:

```
<ul ng-controller="itemCtrl">
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in items">

        <a ng-href="/item/{{item.$id}}">{{item.title}}</a>

            <div class="item-actions">

                <a ng-if="!item.isBookmarked" ng-click="addUserBookmark(item)" class="addBM" href="">Bookmark Item</a> 

                <a ng-if="item.isBookmarked" ng-click="deleteUserBookmark(item)" class="deleteBM" href="">Remove Bookmark</a>

            </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently, the service and controller employed to bookmark items is set up as follows:

```
.controller('itemCtrl', function ($scope, itemService, User) {

    $scope.items = itemService.all;

    $scope.addUserBookmark = function(item){
        var user = User;
        itemService.addBookmark(user, item);
    };

})

.service('itemService', function($firebase, RootURL, User) {

    var rootRef = new Firebase(RootURL);

    var itemArray = $firebase(rootRef.child('item')).$asArray();

    return: {
        all: return itemArray;
        addBookmark: function (user, item) {

            var itemData = {
                itemID: item.$id,
                title: item.title,
            };

            var userData = {
                userID: user.userID,
                username: user.username
            };

            var itemBookmarks = $firebase(rootRef.child('items').child(itemData.itemID).child('bookmarks')).$asArray();

            itemBookmarks.$add(userData);

        },
    };
})
```

I am somewhat of a novice to this area, and I could be going about this entirely the wrong way. So, needless to say, I would be very grateful for any advice as how to proceed. I'm guessing I should set up a query, but as currently set up, the bookmarks are saved as Firebase records with unique record names that make me unsure what to query, when to query, and how to query in an efficient manner. (I apologize if any answer to this question is of exceeding breadth.)

**------Update re: Data Structure-------**

Root FBURL

- Users

  - Username
  - Email
  - ...
  - Bookmarks?

    - ItemID
- Items

  - ItemID
  - Title
  - ...
  - Bookmarks?

    - UserID

I understand that there are more optimal data structures available (perhaps having bookmarks occupy its own top-level tree), but I thought it best to use a more conventional approach until I more fully understand the basics of working with data in Firebase.

And for another attempt at a more simplified question: **how do I query the database to see if a user has bookmarked a certain item?**

Comment: Your use-case is clear, but I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you reduce the amount of text and have a single, answerable (so not "what am I doing wrong?" or "can you help me?") question in there? It might also be helpful if you include a sample of your Firebase data structure.

Comment: Ha, my apologies, @Frank. Excessive amounts of text is definitely an illness acquired through my profession, but I'll try my best to keep it succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You're combining some complex technologies in your application, yet your question seems mostly related to querying Firebase itself. In this answer I will focus on how to query with [Firebase's standard Web/JavaScript API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/).

I would recommend making the bookmarks top-level, instead of nesting them into the user's or item's data. This comes directly from [Firebase's recommendation to avoid building deeply nested hierarchies](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html).

```
Users: [
    {
      Username: "AJeezy9",
      Email: "AJeezy9@stackoverflow.com"
    },
    {
      Username: "Frank van Puffelen",
      Email: "puf@stackoverflow.com"
    }
],
Items: [
    {
      Title: "How to check if user has bookmarked item",
      Url: "http://stackoverflow.com/q/26955078/209103"
    },
    {
      Title: "Firebase JavaScript API",
      Url: "https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/"
    },
    {
      Title: "Microsoft Developer Network",
      Url: "https://msdn.microsoft.com/"
    }
    ],
Bookmarks: [
    { User: 0, Item: 0 },
    { User: 0, Item: 1 },
    { User: 1, Item: 1 },
]
```

You can now "loop over" all Items using:

```
ref.child('Items').on('child_added', function(item) {
  // do something with item.val()
});
```

And you can then find all bookmarks for an item, using:

```
var bookmarks = ref.child('Bookmarks')
  .orderByChild('Item')
  .equalTo(parseInt(item.key()))
  .on('value', function(bookmarks) { 
    console.log('"'+item.val().Title+'" has been bookmarked '+bookmarks.numChildren()+' times');
  });
```

The code should be pretty self-explanatory:

1. starting at the Bookmarks node
2. order by the Item
3. select only the Bookmarks whose Item matches
4. get all matching Bookmarks in one go
5. log the number of children

The output:

```
"How to check if user has bookmarked item" has been bookmarked 1 times
"Firebase JavaScript API" has been bookmarked 2 times
"Microsoft Developer Network" has been bookmarked 0 times"
```

JSBin for reference: http://jsbin.com/tineco/2/edit

Comment: Hey @Frank, sincere thanks for taking time to answer this (& other related questions) here. Truly have been a valued aid in my learning process. However, I don't think your answer achieves my less than eloquently stated aims. I'm trying to check if an itemID value within an ng-repeat also exists in the queried list of a user's item bookmarks -- essentially a matching operation. Also, not sure how to create your data structure as each item/bookmark listed does not have a unique parent present in the structure I'm able to create: e.g.,
    Bookmarks: [ **RecordParent** { User: 0, Item: 0 }]

Comment: Did you check the jsbin? It contains the working sample. If that is not what you are looking for, modify your question to more clearly and concisely state your goal. Keep in mind yhat sample data and code beat prose every time.